# Casting and Retrieving a Key Set of a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a method-

```
private void mapSomething(Class<?> dataType){

   if(dataType.isInstance(Map.class)){
      // How do I get the key set of the map
   }
}
```

Method is called like-

```
mapSomething(someHashMap.getClass()); // Hash Map
```

How do I get the key set of the map inside the method?

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually passing in an instance of Map (just its class data).  If you can change your method signature to something like this it'd be easy enough:

```
private void mapSomething(Object data){
    if(data instanceof Map){
        ((Map)data).keySet()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to a `Map` and retrieve the key set. If you want, you can also add unbounded generic parameter `<?>` to the map and set.

But you are only passing in the class of the data type. You also need to pass in the actual instance. E.g.

```
  mapSomething(someHashMap.getClass(), someHashMap)
```

And the implementation becomes:

```
  void mapSomething(Class<?> dataType, Object instance)
  {
       if(dataType.isInstance(Map.class)){
          Map<?,?> map = (Map<?,?>)instance;
          Set<?> keySet = map.keySet(); 
       }
  }
```

Altenatively, you can just pass the instance, and not the class

```
  void mapSomething(Object instance)
  {
       if(instance instanceof Map){
          Map<?,?> map = (Map<?,?>)instance;
          Set<?> keySet = map.keySet(); 
       }
  }
```

Comment: But there is a declaration of the map that is being passed. Can't we use the name (getName) of the dataType to use the map?

Comment: `getName` returns just what it's supposed to, the name of the class. No way to get back to the instance, once you passed in a class.